# MDX from different dimensions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, mdx, ssas-2008

I want to do a sum in my cube depending of different attributes of different dimensions, something 
like this:

```
WITH MEMBER CAJAS_FISICAS 
AS
(CASE [SOCIOS].[JERARQUÍA SOCIOS].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE
WHEN 'CAMPBELL''S SOUP COMPANY' THEN 
CASE WHEN [FACTURACIÓN].[JERARQUÍA FACTURACIÓN].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = 'FACTURACIÓN SALDOS EN PESOS'
THEN CASE WHEN [PRODUCTOS].[JERARQUÍA PRODUCTOS SOCIO].CURRENTMEMBER.MEMBERVALUE = 'CAJAS'
THEN [Measures].[MFSALEQUANTITY]
ELSE 0 END
ELSE 0 END
ELSE 0 END
)


SELECT CAJAS_FISICAS ON 0,
{
[SOCIOS].[JERARQUÍA SOCIOS].MEMBERS 
} ON 1 FROM [Campbells SellOut Cube]
```

but without the need to drag from the cube those members in order to calculate the value.

If I execute this I get the result but only if I include all the members listed above in the query.

I have tried also the existing function with no luck.

Comment: You're using MSSQL, right?  (I'm guessing from the (non-standard?) square brackets)  What is the relevant structure of your tables?

Comment: Yes I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services 2008, and about the tables you can check this image http://oi61.tinypic.com/2entbt5.jpg, basically the kncustomerdeterminant is related to sellout_customer_determinants, in there there's an identifier (knvendorsellout) which tells you which customer the info will be, in the case of Campbell's, I want to sum the MFSALEQUANTITY considering a KNBILLTYPE, then check IF KNPRODUCTMEASURE is a case unit of measure and lastly divide it by KXPACKAGINGSIZE from sellout_master_products, I want to know is this is possible. Thank you

Comment: WHY ARE YOU SHOUTING? It won't get you answers any more quickly, it's rather rude, and frankly it's very annoying. It's clear from the body of your question that your CAPS LOCK is not stuck. There are Shift keys on both sides of the keyboard to make them easy to reach, because properly cased text is much easier to read. Please save us the trouble of having to edit your questions by properly using the Shift key (including in the title of questions). Thanks.

Comment: Also, the proper way to post an answer is to write an actual answer (in the space provided to do so below). See [help/self-answer] for more information. I'm rolling back your edit for that reason.